# where sharepoint site collection images stores i mean in local folder ?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have uploaded one image into Site Collection Images library for a site .
I just want to know that in which local folder the image getting stored?

Answer (score 0):

Contents in the SharePoint List and Libraries are stored sharePoint Content database. This is not stored in the local file system.

Answer (score 0):

`c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14 (SharePoint 2010)` would be the local location for _layouts url path.